# Настройка nginx на отдачу файлов с одинаковым именем из разных папок

Tags: linux, nginx

У меня есть папки и файлы, которые структурированы примерно так:

```
-root/111/content.csv
-root/112/content.csv
-root/113/content.csv
-root/114/content.csv
```

Я хочу, чтобы при запросе типа `http://someurl/download/111` мне возвращался файл `content.cvs` из папки `111`. Как мне правильно поправить такую захордкоженную конфигурацию:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /download/ {
        alias /home/root/111/conent.csv;
    }
}
```

?

Comment: index прописать content.cvs?

Comment: Как это сделать ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться директивой `rewrite`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /download/ {
        root /home/root/;
        rewrite /download/(.*)$ /$1/content.cvs break;
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем, есть же try_files